# to pause and resume caputured webcam video (Qtmultimedia 5.0-qml-ubuntu)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, camera, qml

I am using Qtmultimedia 5.0 to record and capture video from webcam. The example provided by Qt helped me very much. I could record and stop the captured video using the following code.

```
Camera {
id: camera
}

Rectangle{
Text{
text: qsTr("Record")
}
MouseArea{
onClicked: camera.videoRecorder.record()

}
}

Rectangle{
Text{
text: qsTr("Stop")
}
MouseArea{
onClicked: camera.stop()

}
}
```

Now i need the pause and resume the webcam video. Is there any function to do that job. If I resume the video it should append to the opened file.

Answer (score 0):

just want to let you know that you can use **Qt Media Encoding Library** for that task.
It is here - http://kibsoft.ru